# how to assign states in a DQN (Deep Q-Network)?

Tags: c#, python, unity-game-engine, neural-network, q-learning

I am making a flight simulation with autopilot so i need to make a DQN (Deep Q-Network) to control the autopilot but i don't know the optimal number of states.

the simulation is done in unity and all the environment and physics are done too, the DQN will only need to output (W,A,S,D) to control the plane, i found a code that controls CARTPOLE which in theory should be able to train and control the plane just fine, the only problem is that i don't exactly know if the states i chose are the right ones or not.

this is the code:

```
    
    import os
    import random
    import gym
    import numpy as np
    from collections import deque
    from keras.models import Sequential
    from keras.layers import Dense
    from keras.optimizers import Adam



    class DQNAGENT:

        def __init__(self,state_size,_action_size):

            self.state_size = state_sizes
            self.action_size = actions_sizes
            self.memory = deque(maxlen=2000)
            self.gamma = 0.95
            self.epsilon = 1.00
            self.epsilon_decay_rate = 0.995
            self.epsilon_min = 0.01
            self.learning_rate = 0.001
            self.model = self.build_model()

        def buildmodel(self):

            model = Sequential()
            model.add(Dense(24, input_dim=self.state_size, activation='relu'))
            model.add(Dense(24, activation='relu'))
            model.add(Dense(self.action_size, activation='linear'))
            model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer=Adam(lr=self.learning_rate))
            return model

        def remember(self, state, action, reward, next_state, done):

            self.memory.append((state, action, reward, next_state, done))

        def act(self, state):

            if np.random.rand()  self.epsilon_min:
                self.epsilon *= self.epsilon_decay_rate

        def load(self, name):

            self.model.load_weights(name)

        def save(self, name):

            self.model.save_weights(name)


    def main():
        #environemnet variables
        state_sizes=0
        actions_sizes=4
        #training Variables
        batch_size=32
        n_episodeds=100
        output_directory= 'model_output/autopilot'
        if not os.path.exists(output_directory):
            os.makedirs(output_directory)

        agent = DQNAGENT(state_sizes,actions_sizes)
        done = False

        for e in range(n_episodeds):
            state = #states of the game
            for time in range(5000):
                action = agent.act(state)
                #next_state, reward, done, _ = ##env.step(action)
                #put the next state from unity
                reward = reward if not done else -10
                agent.remember(state, action, reward, next_state, done)
                state = next_state
                if len(agent.memory) > batch_size:
                    agent.replay(batch_size)
```

where the agent class is the agent that will be trained those functions are okay but in the **Main** the state sizes are set to **zero** because i don't know yet the number also these three lines i can't convert to be able to run on my project

```
state = #states of the game
action = agent.act(state)
next_state, reward, done, _ = ##env.step(action)
```

the original code had these lines as :

```
env = gym.make('CartPole-v1')
state_size = env.observation_space.shape[0]
state = env.reset()
next_state, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)
```

because it gets these variables from the Gym package but i need to enter these manually, my environment will consist of **airspeed,plane position, airport position,etc** that's what i think will be write so if someone can help me figure out if this is correct or even better tell me what will be the optimal states will be really appreciated.

the excepted result is something like this.

```
statesizes = 4
states= "how to write those states in this variable"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The states are simply the information your agent has in the current "frame/step".
It's what the agent NEEDS in order to choose an action `agent.act(state)`.

In the **CartPole** example, the state is a box of 4 values:

- Cart Position
- Cart Velocity
- Pole Angle
- Pole Velocity At Tip

In your flight autopilot, the state would be the information you need your agent to have in order to make its decision, e.g:

- Current lattitude
- Current speed
- ...